# Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not convert constant test expression to string.'

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

The below `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient` query:

```
var deviceName = "test";
var pendingRequest = await tableClient
                    .QueryAsync<AttestationDetailWrapper>(x => x.DeviceName == deviceName )
                    .AnyAsync(req.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
```

Throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not convert constant test expression to string.'`

The table is created and empty with the fields `PartitionKey`, `RowKey`, `Timestamp` and `DeviceName` as in the below Azure Storage Explorer:

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]

The classes are below:

```
public class AttestationDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // Unique attestation request (device can register again in future).
    public string DeviceName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Guid Tenant { get; set; } // Tenant to which this registration belongs.
}

internal sealed class AttestationDetailWrapper : AttestationDetail, ITableEntity
{
    public string PartitionKey
    {
        get => Tenant.ToString();
        set => Tenant = Guid.Parse(value);
    }

    public string RowKey
    {
        get => Id.ToString();
        set => Id = Guid.Parse(value);
    }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for inserting the entity as well?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri I haven't got that far yet, my table is blank, I was doing a query and didn't want to clutter with the write code (incase that is wrong). Essentially for the above I am checking a table with the right columns but no rows.

Comment: Understood. Is there a reason you are using `.AnyAsync(req.HttpContext.RequestAborted)`?

Comment: No I may very likely be using the entire API incorrectly. For the above case I want to query if a record with matching DeviceName already exists..so I am open to any constructs

Comment: Please try by removing this. All of the examples I have seen just make use of `QueryAsync` to get the entities.